# Is it safe to delete the contents of ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS Device Logs?

Tags: xcode

The directory `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS Device Logs` contains a bunch of files dating back to 2013 (that I presume to be logs from my iOS devices that I've tested on) that total up to 4.3GB. Is it safe to delete them all?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes It is **SAFE** to do so, as I was short of memory and I found out that iOS Device Logs was using Giga Bytess of it.

I just removed it, and Xcode is running my apps without any issue.